# Is it possible to use c++ as back-end for Electron.js?

Tags: javascript, c++, electron

I have a task to make simple c++ app which stores information into binary files, then need to make simple manipulations with this info, like edit,delete,read.
I wanted to create desktop app using Electron for designing UI and to use c++ for manipulation with information.

Is it possible? And how can i include c++ into electron?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Electron is using nodejs, so you can still package cpp code as a node module and then use it as dependency in your electron app.

See the Hello World example [here](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) which basically does this:

```
module.exports.hello = () => 'world';
```

This is the example from their tutorial:

```
// hello.cc
#include <node.h>

namespace demo {

using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Value;

void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "world"));
}

void init(Local<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "hello", Method);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, init)

}  // namespace demo
```